# Accessing Mutidimension knockout array where dimension is known at runtime using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jslint

I have a situation where i need to access to multidimension knockout
array with coordinates not known until runtime.

Possible knockout arrays (it can be any one of those not known until runtime)

```
self.customers[0]
self.customers[0][0]
self.customers[0][0][0]
self.customers[0][0][0][0]
self.customers[0][0][0][0][0]
```

I have a code which give me array combination in a string literal like below

```
level = "[0]"
level = "[0][0]"
level = "[0][0][0]"
level = "[0][0][0][0]"
level = "[0][0][0][0][0]"
```

evaluating the value in array in the below fashion

```
  arr = arr.concat(eval('self.customers()' + level));
```

I know this works and it's a bad way. JSlint says "eval is evil"

**> Is there a better way to access array self.customers()[i][j[k]... where i,j,k... can be built at runtime**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a Knockout-related question. In any case, there are several ways to solve this without using `eval`, some more clever than others. Here's a straightforward (though not necessarily the most elegant) way to do it.

Suppose:

```
var self = {
    customers: [[[1],[[2,3,4],5]],[6],[7,[8,9]]]
};

var level = "[0][1][0][2]";
```

Expected output would be "4". Now first find the levels, e.g. using a regex:

```
var myLevels = level.match(/\d+/g);
```

And use a recursive function to traverse the into the multi-dimensional array:

```
function multiDimensionFind(data, levels) {
    var result = data[levels[0]];
    if (result instanceof Array) {
        levels.splice(0, 1);
        return multiDimensionFind(result, levels);
    }
    return result;
}

var x = multiDimensionFind(self.customers, myLevels);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnbDY/1/) to see it in action.

PS. I'd rethink your design ;-)

Comment: this works great. only thing i a am missing how to get the value as observable assuming self.customers is knockout observable

Comment: You'll probably get best response if you post a follow-up question (perhaps link to this one), with the Knockout-specific code/problem. Try to put the *minimal code to repro* in the question, and if at all possible add a fiddle (possibly fork mine) to demonstrate the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function which returns the correct level based on the input. Something like this

```
var getLevel = function (arr, levels) {
    var retArr = arr(); 
    while(levels) {
        try {
            var currLvl = parseInt(levels.substring(1,2)); //get first level
            if (retArr) {
                retArr = retArr[currLvl]; //navigate to given level
            } else {
                //what happens if the array doesn't have enough levels?
            }
            levels = levels.substring(3); // go to next level
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
            //what should happen if the levels string has a wrong format?
        }
    }

    return retArr;
}
```

Of course, you should also define what needs to happen when the input isn't valid or it's undefined.

You would then call this method as such : `getLevel(self.customers, level);`, thus avoiding eval :)